# Porting VBA To IronPython

Tags: vba, ironpython, porting

I am trying to translate the VBA code found in [this link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/sortws.aspx) into IronPython. Can anyone recommend a good VBA resource to explain how best to do this for a Python programmer?

I have all the Excel portions implemented, such as the treatment and use of objects, workbooks, worksheets, etc.

I will also settle for an explanation of this snippet of code:

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Put the index value of the sheet into Arr. Ensure there
' are no duplicates. If Arr(N) is not zero, we've already
' loaded that element of Arr and thus have duplicate sheet
' names.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If Arr(N) > 0 Then
    ErrorText = "Duplicate worksheet name in NameArray."
    SortWorksheetsByNameArray = False
    Exit Function
End If
```

why would Arr(N) ever NOT be greater than 0?

Here is my current code, which is broken:

```
def move_worksheets_according_to_list(self, name_list):
    wb = self.com_workbook
    temp_list = []
    for n in range(len(name_list)):
        if name_list.count(name_list[n]) > 1:
            raise Exception("Duplicate worksheet name in NameArray.")
        else:
            temp_list.append(wb.Worksheets(name_list[n]).Index)

    for m in range(len(temp_list)):
        for n in range(m, len(temp_list)):
            if temp_list[n] < temp_list[m]:
                l = temp_list[n]
                temp_list[n] = temp_list[m]
                temp_list[m] = l

    if not all(temp_list[i] <= temp_list[i+1] for i in xrange(len(temp_list)-1)):
        return False

    print "current order"
    for sheet in wb.Worksheets:
        print sheet.Name
    wb.Worksheets(name_list[0]).Move(Before=wb.Worksheets(1))
    #WB.Worksheets(NameArray(LBound(NameArray))).Move before:=WB.Worksheets(Arr(1))
    for n in range(len(name_list)-1):
        print 'moving ', name_list[n], 'before ', name_list[n+1]
        wb.Worksheets(name_list[n]).Move(Before=wb.Worksheets(name_list[n + 1]))
```

Note:

With [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6768674/1146308) as reference, here is all I had to do:

```
def move_worksheets_according_to_list(self, name_list):
    wb = self.com_workbook
    l = []
    # since wb.Worksheets is a com_object, you can't use the "if _ in XXX"
    # construct without converting to a list first
    for s in wb.Worksheets:
        l.append(s.Name)

    for n in range(len(name_list)):
        if name_list[n] in l:
            wb.Worksheets(name_list[n]).Move(After=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
```

Comment: @JackOrangeLantern There is absolutely nothing wrong with `I'm` and I do not see why you are changing every English contraction. They are standard usage http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_(grammar)

Comment: @Remou Contractions are standard in informal usage, not in formal usage, which the wiki article makes clear. See Strunk and White for reference. However, it has been made clear to me that contractions are standard practice for SO. I will alter my practices accordingly. Thank you for noting my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

def move_worksheets_according_to_list(self, name_list):
    wb = self.com_workbook
    l = []
    # since wb.Worksheets is a com_object, you can't use the "if _ in XXX"
    # construct without converting to a list first
    for s in wb.Worksheets:
        l.append(s.Name)

```
for n in range(len(name_list)):
    if name_list[n] in l:
        wb.Worksheets(name_list[n]).Move(After=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Declaring and dimensioning an array of longs in VBA will create the array with the default value of 0 in each slot.